# How can I clear all checkboxes from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this method for get the value from objects selected, and the ".length" for indicate at the user how many objects are selected. but I would like to have a Cancel button and clear all the checkboxes and reset my ".length"

```
$scope.selection = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(image) {


    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(image);
    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    // is newly selected
    else {
        $scope.selection.push(image);
    }

    $scope.totalitems = $scope.selection.length;

    $scope.itemobject = {
        'attachments': $scope.selection
    };
```

this is my ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-repeat="image in images | filter:query as attachmensresults">
                        <li>
                            <div class="cbxdelete">
                                <input class="checkbx" id="ckBox" type="checkbox" value="{{image.id}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(image.id) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(image.id)" />
                            </div>
                            <a href="{{image._links.file.href}}" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
                                <div class="img-preview">
                                    <img ng-src="{{image._links.file.href}}" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
<button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>

$scope.cancel = function(){
   $scope.selection = [];
   $scope.totalitems = 0; 
   $scope.itemobject = { 'attachments': $scope.selection };
}
```

This will reset your selection array to be empty, so ng-checked will be false.

Comment: There's a bit more state to clean up:   

    `$scope.totalitems = 0;
    $scope.itemobject = {
      'attachments': $scope.selection
    };`

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a `selected` property to your `images` array. This makes changing your model easier because you can use two-way binding with `ng-model="image.selected"`.

To clear all you have to loop over each image. 
Looping over all items is probably a bit slower then your code but I think it's less code and easier to read.

You shouldn't use ids inside of ng-repeat (`id="ckBox"`). Because ids should be unique in a page.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/4h7kLoL1/).

If you need the selected images as a separate array you could use `map` to create a new array. See method `post` as an example.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($filter) {
    var vm = this,
        changeAll = function(state) {
            angular.forEach(vm.images, function(image, index) {
                image.selected=state;
            });    
        };
    
    this.images = [
        {id: 1, url: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/',selected: false},
        {id: 2, url: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/',selected: false},
        {id: 3, url: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/',selected: false}
    ];
    
    this.cancel = function() {
        changeAll(false);
    };
    
    this.selectAll = function() {
        changeAll(true);
    };
    
    this.post = function() {
        var mapped = vm.images.map(function(image,index) {
            return {
                id: image.id,
                selected: image.selected
            };
        });
        alert($filter('json')(mapped));
    }
}

MainController.$inject = ['$filter'];
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
  <button ng-click="main.post()">send</button>
  <button ng-click="main.selectAll()">all</button>
  <button ng-click="main.cancel()">cancel</button>{{main.images|json}}
  <ul ng-repeat="image in main.images">
    <li>
      <div class="cbxdelete">
        <input class="checkbx" type="checkbox" value="{{image.id}}" ng-model="image.selected" />
      </div>
      <a href="{{image.url}}" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
        <div class="img-preview">
          <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="" />
        </div>
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```